# Website Restrict Google Maps API key dynamicly via SDK

Tags: google-maps

**my question**: Is there any Google API / SDK I can use to be able to dynamically add "HTTP referrers (web sites)" (assign domains) to maps API key ?

### Background

I'm building a web-application portal that will allow anyone to create a business website and assign a custom domain to it.

On that generated website customer will have google maps map pointing to address of their business.

Customer has an option to add custom domain to their business website created by my web-application (by CNAME to the my web-application)

Desired feature is that once the domain background job will get triggered  that will add that domain/host to list of restricted domains/hosts for my Google Maps Api key so that their domain will be able to read google maps on their domanin

> note: I Have cron job DNS lookup validation check implemented to ensure that domain is really assigned to the domain

### live example

here is website generated by customer on my web-application http://sbs-sos.sajtka.sk/  he assigned a domain and pointed CNAME  http://sbs-sos.sk/

Reason why the google map works is because I manually white-listed their domain. I need to automate this

> please aware portal is not fully launched so many bugs are happening

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good idea. Why do you need to give other people free rein to use your API keys?

Comment: this is not to give other people access to my API keys. My application is creating websites for those clients.And they can assign domain for that website => Ineed to be able to whitelist their domain for my API key

Answer (score 2):

The feature request to manage API keys restrictions via SDK was submitted in Google issue tracker in 2016:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829646

Currently, there are no any official SDK for that. However, the last update from Google says that they released experimental API to programmatically manage your API Keys and their restrictions.

> The best way to handle thousands of authorized domains is to use an API to programmatically manage your API Keys and their restrictions, and we have recently launched a new service that allows you to do this.
>
> This API is still in Alpha. If you are interested in becoming a Trusted Tester for this service, you can use the following form to sign up, please read the instructions carefully:
>   https://forms.gle/qx2SMcarWCAsbWVp7
>
> Please note that this API is not part of the Google Maps Platform. After you fill out the form, you will be contacted by the API Keys API team with instructions on how to get started, and how to receive support.
>
> API Keys API is currently free of charge. However, please note that use of Cloud Endpoints may be subject to charges at high traffic volume. You can check the pricing sheet here:
>   https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/pricing-and-quotas

I would suggest joining Trusted Tester program and try out this API.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, I've signed up of the program waitng for approval. I'll explore their API features. I will leave this bounty open for little while and if no better solution pops up till then I'll Accept the answer  (&Bounty) .

Comment: bounty accepted.But I'll accept this answer as soon as I get my hands on google beta features and test this. Currently my application is still pending

Comment: @equivalent8 I'm in a similar situation. Did you received the alpha access through the formular and did you had the chance to work with them or did you find a different solution?

Comment: For ppl who pass across this issue: Access to the Alpha Keys API got granted quickly and does excactly what I need.